# How to use ExclusiveStartKey in scan operation without sortKey and LastEvaluatedKey in Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been using ExclusiveStartKey for a Scan Operation in DynamoDB for a table named 'sample' which does not have a Sort key...just a partition key. It constantly throws an error : "The provided starting key is invalid". I cannot figure out what is going wrong here. My code works fine for table that have sort key. Also, there is no option to use LastEvaluatedKey. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You only use an ExclusiveStartKey when you get returned a LastEvaluatedKey. If there is no LastEvaluatedKey in the response it means you have already read the entire dataset and there is no more pages to retrieve.

Comment: I understand Sir..but what if I want to read the table again starting from a particular item of the table?

Comment: Simply do a Scan request and add `Limit=1` and see what the LastEvaluatedKey looks like. Then create your ExclusiveStartKey based on that. But it's not recommended to manufacture an ESK, typically it would mean your access patterns/schema needs tweaking.